# Is this inversion correct?

Tags: grammar, inversion

Could you please tell me if I have used inversion correctly or not?

> On no account can reforms be postponed any longer.

Comment: I believe in this sentence _fronting_ triggers _inversion_, and the writer has shifted  the emphasis by inverting the syntax. Yes, the sentence reads fine.

Comment: A related (possible duplicate) question has an answer saying [*This kind of inversion, which is rather literary, is required when a negative polarity item is brought to the front of the clause, eg **Never, Scarcely, Only** (introducing a phrase or a clause), **On no account**, etc.*](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/271429/126)

Answer (score 0):

Yes. This sentence is correct and idiomatic.

Comment: You can't just "_Dirac_" answers: you must flesh them out. That is not even a comment, I'm sorry to say.

Comment: @eded: Your answer has been flagged as 'low quality' probably because of its length. It came up in the review queue. Would you be able to explain it further? Single line answers (in most situations) are less likely to be salvageable, I'm afraid. People flag them for incineration.

Comment: The question was is this correct. The answer is yes. To me, it seems the poster understands and no more is needed. I don't mind getting downvoted, I'm just trying to help people

Comment: @User40475 what does Diracing an answer mean?

Comment: @Richard: _Dirac's taciturn and retiring behavior are famous; in his days at Cambridge, a unit of volubility called a dirac meant one word per year._ (copied from the internet)